Is "an English textbook" ambiguous?

This is an English textbook for Japanese high school students.

Which of the following is correct?
(1) The textbook is written in English.
(2) The textbook is a textbook on the English language.

@ishtar I believe "English book" is ambiguous, but I didn't think "English textbook" was ambiguous. Thank you very much, ishtar.

I add to @ishtar's comments.
About textbooks, it’s quite meaningless to pre-modify the book name with English just to say it’s written in that language.
(A possibility of using this method is in naming shelves in libraries or shops for more general books, like English fiction, and so on.)
For text books, the pre-modifier English is more likely
the subject name.
Modifications to tell readers about the language used in the text is likely in the form (written) in English after the book title.
